# Reading out raster data from multiple regions into xyz format in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I‘m trying to export maize yield data from a raster to some sort of text file in order to analyze the data statistically. So far I‘ve managed to do so for an entire country (France), so that I ended up with a table containing the coordinates of about 8000 10x10km squares with the corresponding yield data (see pictures)

[image]

[image]

Now, data on country level is not precise enough for my purpose, I need to know for each square at least the region (department) it is located in. Extracting each department individually is way too tedious, especially considering that I will have to do the same for multiple other European countries.

Is there a way to easily extract the yield data from the raster so that I know in which department each square is located?

Comment: Use Make XY Event layer to add your excel table to arcgis as Points (you might also need to make a copy of the Points to make them permanent), then Intersect with counties. You will then get your table in the screenshot including a county column. With 8000 pixels, it should also be possible to use Raster To Point, then Intersect with counties

Comment: That sounds smart, I will definitely try it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Screenshots are far more legible than pictures. Please post from the workstation where possible.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Make XY Event layer to add your excel table to arcgis as Points (you might also need to make a copy of the Points to make them permanent), then Intersect with counties. You will then get your table in the screenshot including a county column.

With 8000 pixels, it should also be possible to use Raster To Point, then Intersect with counties